# In react-native how can i add watermark on images both ios and android

Tags: image, react-native, watermark

In react-native, I want to add watermark on images both in android and ios.

I had tried https://github.com/JimmyDaddy/react-native-image-marker it works fine in ios but in android, I am not able to get the image path after the watermark is applied, how can I append a watermark on images in both ios and android.

`"react-native": "0.61.4",
"react-native-image-marker": "^0.6.1",`

*expected image as shown below*
[image]

Answer (score -4):

create a view with position absolute. refer below example, replace the pos with your location. put 0 if you want it in centre

```
<View  
   style={{
       position: 'absolute',
       top: pos,
       left: pos,
       right: pos,
       bottom: pos
         }}>
  <Text>water mark txt</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I know it's an old thread and this answer is down voted. But, you can use this solution by using `react-native-view-shot` to capture the view and turn it to a final image